Next js middleware cause this "app-pages-internals.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at app-pages-internals.js:1:1)"
I am using NextJS 14 app router and I can't go back because site is in prod.
What I am trying to do is when fetch user is called i update route in cookie (route coming from server) at first everything works fine, even routes were protected, but as soon as I implement this method I get this error
app-pages-internals.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at app-pages-internals.js:1:1)
page.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at page.js:1:1)
Understand this error
webpack.js?v=1725952128143:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at webpack.js?v=1725952128143:1:1)
Understand this error
main-app.js?v=1725952128143:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at main-app.js?v=1725952128143:1:1)
Understand this error
layout.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at layout.js:1:1)

My middleware file
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'

const PROTECTED_ROUTES = [
  '/clips',
  '/find-clips',
  '/setting/basic-info',
  '/setting/user-plan',
  '/contact-us',
]

const SUBSCRIPTION_REQUIRED_ROUTES = [
  '/find-clips',
  '/clips',
]

const UNAUTHENTICATED_ONLY_ROUTES = [
  '/login',
  '/register',
  '/forgot-password',
  '/forgot-email',
]

function isAuthenticated(request) {
  return !!request.cookies.get('access_token')
}

function isSubscribed(request) {
  return request.cookies.get('sub-token')?.value === 'true'
}

function hasUuid(request) {
  return !!request.cookies.get('uuid')
}

function redirectTo(path, request) {
  console.log(`Redirecting to: ${path}`)
  return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(path, request.url))
}

export function middleware(request) {
  const { pathname } = request.nextUrl
  const profileRoute = request.cookies.get('profile-route')?.value
  const userDataFetched = request.cookies.get('user-data-fetched')?.value === 'true'

  console.log(`Current pathname: ${pathname}`)
  console.log(`Profile route: ${profileRoute}`)
  console.log(`User data fetched: ${userDataFetched}`)

  // If user data hasn't been fetched, allow the request to proceed
  if (!userDataFetched && isAuthenticated(request)) {
    return NextResponse.next()
  }

  if (!isAuthenticated(request)) {
    if (PROTECTED_ROUTES.some(route => pathname.startsWith(route))) {
      return redirectTo('/login', request)
    }
    if (pathname.startsWith('/update-phone') || pathname.startsWith('/verify-phone')) {
      return redirectTo('/', request)
    }
    if (!hasUuid(request) && pathname.startsWith('/confirm-registration')) {
      return redirectTo('/', request)
    }
  } else {
    if (profileRoute && pathname !== profileRoute && !pathname.startsWith('/api/')) {
      return redirectTo(profileRoute, request)
    }
    if (!isSubscribed(request) && SUBSCRIPTION_REQUIRED_ROUTES.some(route => pathname.startsWith(route))) {
      return redirectTo('/price-plan', request)
    }
    if (UNAUTHENTICATED_ONLY_ROUTES.some(route => pathname.startsWith(route))) {
      return redirectTo('/', request)
    }
  }

  return NextResponse.next()
}

export const config = {
  matcher: '/:path*',
} 

and my fetch user
import Cookies from "js-cookie";
import { requestWithAuth } from "./apiService";

export const fetchUserData = async (router, showToaster, dispatch, saveUser) => {
    try {
        if (!localStorage.getItem('login_email')) {
            return
        }
        const email = localStorage.getItem('login_email')
        const response = await requestWithAuth('GET', `/users/get-user`, {}, router, showToaster);
        if (response) {
            localStorage.setItem('logined_uuid', response.uuid)
            localStorage.setItem('allowYoutube', response.allowYoutube)
            localStorage.setItem('allowTwitch', response.allowTwitch)
            localStorage.setItem('allowDownload', response.allowDownload)
            Cookies.set('sub-token', response.is_active)
            Cookies.set('profile-route', response.profile_status);

            // Set a flag to indicate user data has been fetched
            Cookies.set('user-data-fetched', 'true', { expires: 1 });
            if (saveUser) {
                dispatch(saveUser(response))
            }
            return response
        }
        return response

    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching user data:', error);
    }
};

I tried other methods but I could find solution according to gpt and and median. My server is sending HTML not JS (I verified it, in response is embedded HTML).
I redirect to page that I want but cause css issue and unusable page
